# React Native - detect Android devices with rounded corners?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, rounded-corners

I have a React Native application where I have an input field at the very bottom of the screen. I'd like to add some extra padding to the bottom of the screen in case the screen of the device has rounded corners, like in the most recent iPhones, Samsungs etc. The purpose of this would be to take the input field from the bottom a bit further from the virtual home buttons that these devices tend to have at the very very bottom of the screen.

The iPhone devices are quite easy to keep track of since there are only a few of them with rounded corners. But how about keeping track of that with Android devices? Not really that interested if it's with some regex magic or a library for that, but anyone who's done it?

AFAIK the `Platform` library or `react-native-device-info` from the community doesn't help too much with this (or am I wrong?)

Knowing the cases of rounded corners I could then do something like:

```
render() {

        extraPadding = awesomeFunctionToCheckRoundedCorners() ? 15 : 0;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, { paddingBottom: extraPadding }]}>
                {/* My awesome input field here */}
            </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587929/how-to-detect-if-screen-has-rounded-corners-in-react-native